# yii2 - urlmanager routing not working

Tags: php, yii2

Here i have used yii2 configuration with rules

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-backend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [],
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],  
        'urlManager' => [
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'rules' => require(__DIR__ . '/routes.php'), 
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

And given below routes.php

```
<?php
use yii\web\UrlRule;
return array(
// REST routes for CRUD operations
'POST <controller:\w+>s' => '<controller>/create', // 'mode' => UrlRule::PARSING_ONLY will be implicit here
'api/<controller:\w+>s' => '<controller>/index',
'PUT api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/update',// 'mode' => UrlRule::PARSING_ONLY will be implicit here
'DELETE api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/delete', // 'mode' => UrlRule::PARSING_ONLY will be implicit here
'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
// normal routes for CRUD operations
'<controller:\w+>s/create' => '<controller>/create',
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<action:update|delete>' => '<controller>/<action>',
);
```

When i access local2host.com/advanced/backend/web/index.php/country/create -  It's working fine

but when i access through local2host.com/advanced/backend/web/index.php/api/country/create

It's throwing 404 - not found error

Unable to resolve the request "api/country/create".

As per my requirement :
when i access this link local2host.com/advanced/backend/web/index.php/api/country/create
 it should access "country" as controller and "create" as action

Comment: 'POST <controller:\w+>s' => '<controller>/create', changed to 'POST <controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/create',

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have modules. First you need to add your `api` module into your config file:

```
'modules' => [
    'api'
],
```

Second, you need to add module into your rules like below:

```
'<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
'<module:\w+><controller:\w+>/<action:update|delete>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
```

This is remarkable that, you may need to take care of other rules with module and have your own customized rules.